# SBT project in IDEA 14 does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea, intellij-14, sbt-idea

My SBT project imports itself perfectly to IDEA IDE on MacOS, but on the Ubuntu it shows dozens of errors about not being able to resolve symbols.

for example:

```
import play.api.mvc.Action
```

reports `Unused import statement` from withing IDEA

and reference to `Action` several lines afterwards is reported as `Cannot resolve method Action.apply`

The problem is only to be seen in the IDE as sbt run from the command line is perfectly ok.

My current version of the IntelliJ IDEA IDE is 14 Ultimate

Scala plugin version 1.2.1

SBT version on the Ubuntu host 0.13.7

JDK version Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (running Fedora 20). Try with the **EAP** version of Intellij IDEA 14 (see : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP).

Also, you have to use the EAP version of the Scala plugin (**parameters > Frameworks and Languages > Scala > Misc**).

It worked for me.